# How to speed up rendering table of checkboxes in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a series charting tool.  For each series, I have 4 categories.  I want the user to be able to choose any combination of series and category to plot.

To accomplish this, I created a bootstrap modal with a table of checkboxes for each series/category combination using Angular.js.  It works, but I find the rendering of the modal too slow when there are too many series:

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Series Name</th>
        <th ng-repeat="col in cols">
          {{ col }}
        </th>
        <th>select all</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="(name, insts) in items"
          ng-show="([name] | filter:query).length > 0">
        <td>{{ name }}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="inst in insts">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="inst.isSelected">
        </td>
        <td><ui-select-all items="insts" prop="isSelected"></ui-select-all></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

Plunker demo of what I have: http://plnkr.co/edit/1zmZMpDsGwaKdyL7dFty?p=preview

I'm just learning Angular, so I'm not too sure how to speed this up, or if there is a smarter approach than using a big table of checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to speed up any ng-repeat is to use `track by $index`

```
  <tr ng-repeat="(name, insts) in items track by $index"
      ng-show="([name] | filter:query).length > 0">
    <td>{{ name }}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="inst in insts track by $index">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="inst.isSelected">
    </td>
    <td><ui-select-all items="insts" prop="isSelected"></ui-select-all></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: I tried it in the plunker and there wasn't a significant speedup

Comment: also you can replace {{}} with ng-bind, or check out [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce)

Comment: I updated the plunker using bindonce, and the modal still takes a few seconds to show up.  For comparison, if you set num rows to a small number, it loads almost instantly.

Comment: @HarishR Can you elaborate more on "track by $index" please? But it seems to be useless anyway because it really doesn't change the speed at all in the plunker sample

Comment: please read [this article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-using-track-by-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs-1-2.htm)

Comment: i didnt get the reason for the downvote?? whoever downvote's must provide a reason for doing so...